# Is blanch freezing vegetables required for short term storage?

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, freezing, blanching

I need some vegetables to last for about a month until I've juiced them all.

Blanch freezing many vegetables sees them last for periods 6 months and longer, but it's a bit of a hassle.

Would just ziplocking them in the freezer direct give me a month? I'm talking carrots, celery, spinach, zucchini. I'm sucking air out with a dustbuster which is nowhere near a vacuum sealer but hopefully better than not doing it.

Would putting the celery and spinach in a bowl of (sugared) water keep them going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blanching is done to halt enzymatic action that would start to destroy the plant cells. You can freeze without blanching and the veggies will still be edible even after 6 months but their quality will decline faster.

If you are planning on juicing those veggies within a month then you are going to be doing a lot more damage than the freezer will and I don't think you would see much benefit from blanching. The spinach and celery might stay a little greener when it thaws- the carrots and zucchini would probably not be effected at all.

As for the sugar water. Are you planning on freezing them in the water? I don't think that would do much but dilute their juices when the ice crystals rip them apart. Of course you wouldn't be able to keep spinach in a bowl of water for a month- that would be more like a swamp than food.

Comment: I'm not planning on freezing with the sugar water, just having them sit on the bench. I only considered sugar because I seem to recall flowers in a vase last longer with a bit of sugar in the water.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered taking an hour or two and juicing all your vegetables at the same time?  Put them in separate containers like they type you would get Chinese soup in?  In essence you’re doing the same thing, but in a different order without the blanching, sugaring or extra work.  The plastic they use for Chinese food freezes without splitting, and then can put in micro for defrost, or just put in fridge the night before. (Can be purchased at party store or Costco)  Also leave a little room at the top of the container for expansion so the container doesn't bulge.

I like using Freezer Zip Locks.  Once filled and air removed, they store flat on the bottom and makes it easier to stack.  When you need it, put it in a bowl or plate and defrost in fridge. And you don't have to worry about expansion.

Also Celery stays much longer in the fridge if you wrap it in foil.  I have had celery stay fresh for a month.

Comment: Interesting idea about doing all the juicing at once, although I tend to juice the fruit and veges that I feel like at the time. Nice tip about the celery in foil.

Comment: When you freeze veg or fruit juice, it tends to give you big crystals that can easily break apart in a blender adding a little warm liquid. You could use smaller zip locks, even sandwich bags (just don't toss around when frozen).  It just may give you the flexiblity you are looking for.  Just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Some great ideas up there but here is one for getting the air out of freezer bags is dump the DustBuster and use a straw. I close the ziplock as much as possible and slip a straw in the opening and suck the air out. As soon as the bag collapses around your food close it the rest of the way.